# Android Text Rendering

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fonts

I'm trying to display a TextView in my app but when testing it with a real phone the fonts render badly but works with the emulator.

I tried taking a screenshot to show what I mean but when viewing the screenshot on my PC the font appears normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dp in xml, e.g. 10dp.
[Wiki - Pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)

Comment: Just tested it from 10 to 20 dp and sp. Same issue.